# error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

When defining a double type it gives this error
but the error to the ethical one when clicking the button to save

I have already made several attempts to invoke in several different types and nothing

```
public void save(View view){

        if ( validateFields() ){
            moviment = new Moviment();
            String date = fieldDate.getText().toString();
            Double valueRecovery = Double.parseDouble(fieldValue.getText().toString());

            moviment.setValue( valueRecovery );
            moviment.setCategory( fieldCategory.getText().toString() );
            moviment.setDescription( fieldDescription.getText().toString() );
            moviment.setDate( date );
            moviment.setType( "Expense" );

            Double expensA = totalExpense + valueRecovery;
            expenseAt( expensA  );

            moviment.save( date );

            finish();


        }


    }


The expected output is that it is saved in the firebase but causes this error
```